# Hover leaving Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

When we apply a hover effect on an element (like a div to have a box-shadow when hovered over) with transition of 1s.
It gets an animation when hovered but as soon as u move the mouse away, it has no transition, it just drastically returns to the state.

How do you give a transition of like 1s for when we leave the hover state?

I saw a few codes but couldn't see what was making it happen.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}

div:hover {
  animation: nav 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes nav {
  to {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I recommend creating two classes and use javascript to transition... or just use jQuery

Comment: @Si8 can u provide me with a specific line of code for it

Comment: this is because you haven't defined a `from` state in your keyframes. However, you don't need keyframes, just :hover is sufficient as Justin shows in his answer

Comment: I added an answer... no need for keyframe for the box shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw so a right answers above but here is another solution by JavaScript using `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events, but I notice you to use `.hover`, because it's simple.

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```
    <div id="d"></div>
```

```
const d = document.getElementById("d");
d.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
   d.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 2px black";
})
d.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{
   d.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px";
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to do anything. It will transition back when you stop hovering.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
  transition: box-shadow 1s;
}

div:hover {
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with animations for me.

Comment: @Naman you don't need animations. Just use :hover as Justin shows above.

Comment: Yeah the difference is you are using keyframes and I am using transition. Before you posted your code you made it sound like you were talking about CSS transition not keyframes.

Comment: this is because you haven't defined a `from` state in your keyframes. However, you don't need keyframes, just `:hover` is sufficient as Justin shows in his answer

Comment: @Pixelomo `from` doesn't work either :( .
And this is just a simplified version. I m using different animation in my actual code which requires `keyframes`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers, you can also do something like this (non JS/jQuery):

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  background: #CCC;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

/* Create the hidden pseudo-element */
/* include the shadow for the end state */
.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: See I need a leaving transition for when a div has an hover ANIMATION.